# Regex "match up to" (in two cases)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following regex expression which will capture the start of a quote tag and the author in various cases.

I cannot get it to match up to `link=` OR `pid=` (note the space before each of those).

At the moment, I think what is happening is the expression is matching indiviual letters, instead of the strings above.

```
\[(quote)\]?\s*(?:author)?=?(.[^link=|pid=]+[\w]*).*?\]
```

An example of the string I'm testing the regex on. I'm trying to capture two things: "quote" (which becomes my $1), and then the username (in various cases, which becomes my $2).

The substitution is [$1=$2].

I'm trying to stop the expression at a closing square bracket, so I don't have to deal with the quote tag contents, or the final close tag. The expression only deals with the opening quote tag and attributes.

```
[quote='User Name' pid='1082654' dateline='1411779439']Test[/quote]
```

With the regex expression above, it would match:

```
[quote='User Name' pid]Test[/quote]
```

When it should match everything above, except for the "pid". Here is a more complete example: http://regex101.com/r/iK2nO2/1

How can I more clearly define where the capture group should stop? I'm using this with PHP so I think the PCRE flavor.

Comment: what exactly is the output expected?

Comment: Since the square brackets are used to delimit a character class, writing something like `[^link=|pid=]` doesn't have any sense.

Comment: The sub-expression `[^link=|pid=]+` matches one or more consecutive characters not among "link=|pid".  What are you actually trying to match, and out of that, what are you trying to capture?

Comment: The expected output would be [quote='User Name']Test[/quote]

Comment: When the 'author' attribute is present, can you rely on it to be the first one?  Also, do you need to fully validate the tag format?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, when the author attribute is present, the username (capture) is always the first one. I'm unsure about your next question.

Comment: Do you need to deal with nested tags?  Where can whitespace appear in your tags other than separating tagname and attributes?

Comment: Is regex really the best tool for this job? It would seem that simple parsing could suffice.

Comment: By "fully validate the tag format" I mean must you avoid matching malformed tags, such as `[quote author=me no_value]` or `[quote author=me 'no attribute name']`.

Comment: Also, do you need to account for the `']'` character appearing in attribute values?

Comment: As you may be gleaning from my line of questioning, I'm inclined to agree with @MikeBrant that regex is probably not the right tool for this job.  To do it right, I think you need to write a *bona fide* parser.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, John. I don't have any conditions for when there is an author attribute in my search string. I'm confident it will always appear without malformed tags. I'm considering an answer below, by the way. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[(quote)\]?\s*(?:author)?=?((?:(?!\s+link|\s+pid).)+).*?\]
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iK2nO2/3

Comment: Many thanks for that, that works fine for me. It's interesting how you matched the second one in that list too (with the $2 being more than simply the author/username).